# Repository Pattern - Java example for composite objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I'm having a hard time understanding the repository pattern.

One thing that I'm not able to understand, what most tutorial suggested, is that a repository should act like a in-memory database, i.e, they should have `add()`, `remove()` , `find()` etc methods. But if I'm not using any persistence framework like `Hibernate`, where should I put the logic to save these objects to database? Should there be a separate *data access layer*?

What happens when a object contains reference to another object?

For example, a `Customer` can have many `Address`(es) and there is an *identifying relationship* between `Customer` and `Address`

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private List<Address> addresses; // one or more addresses


    // ...

}

public class Address {
    protected String street;  
    protected String city;

    // ...
}
```

Should there be two separate repositories for `Customer` and `Address`?

How should such a repository structure looks like if there is a lookup table involved (e.g. A `Book` having an `Owner`, in a *non-identifying relationship*)?

Comment: Well it's a matter of design, you can have addAddress() method inside CustomerDao. Or you can define separate CustomerAddressDao class for customer-address related queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me ,repository pattern is just an object that is responsible for persisting and retrieving domain objects from the underlying storage.

> But if I'm not using any persistence framework like Hibernate, where
>   should I put the logic to save these objects to database? Should there
>   be a separate data access layer?

I do not see any significant benefit to have another data access layer as the repository is already responsible for persist and access data. Just put these logic in the repository. Keep it simple first until you see the benefit to have an extra data access layer.

> What happens when a object contains reference to another object? 
>   Should there be two separate repositories for Customer and Address?

Yes . I would have separate repositories for Customer and Address. Depending on the persisting technology you use, you can get a customer and his addresses together (e.g. use simple JOIN in the JDBC case). Or you can reuse `AddressRepository` by injecting it into `CustomerRepository` to help you to get the address for a customer.